# Apache tomcat7 + couchdb in the same host

Tags: couchdb, tomcat7

I couldn't find any guide on the internet about how to make them work together. I found some couchdb tutorials but they are mostly having the web pages hosted in couchdb's own webserver.

My requirement:

1. Use tomcat 7 (or other versions) - i will be using jsp for the
   website. It has some features that require file upload and
   processing of files, file generation, and etc., that will require
   java. It also has admin console that will require the next item,
2. ExtJS (maybe V4) - I will be needing this in the admin console page for restful access to couchdb and other ui components (sorry
   but I am not considering jquery at the moment because I am already
   familiar with .
3. Couchdb because the client needs a dynamic structure of data.

Now my question is how to make tomcat and couchdb run on the same host (and port of course)? As much as possible I would like to avoid making my pages doing cross domain js calls.

Worst case I may have to create a servlet that overrides put|get|post|delete that calls couchdb (either by using a driver or httpclient).

Comment: No magic: just install CouchDB on your tomcat server (exactly like you'd install it on any PC), and write a .jsp that responds to client requests by opening a CouchDB session (just as a normal Java app would talk to CouchDB).  Two links: [1) Java & CouchDB](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/apache-couchdb-and-java/223100116), [2) Installing a CouchDB- and Tomcat-based application on Ubuntu](http://cemerick.com/2010/05/12/provisioning-administration-and-deployment-of-couchdb-java-tomcat/).  The "local.ini" settings in Link 2) might be useful...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of *course* you can co-locate CouchDB and your web server.

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Use a different language besides Javascript for the server-side stuff.  PHP, Perl, Python, Java - *anything*.  For example, using the [CouchDB HTTP API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API) is trivial from a Tomcat/Java .jsp.

IMHO...

Comment: Thanks paul. I will take your suggestion. But can you elaborate on co-locating them?